# Getting an error 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.'

Tags: c#, automation

I am getting an error:

> The process cannot access the file 'E:\testing\check1.txt' because it
>   is being used by another process.

here is my code:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter("E:\\testing\\check1.txt");
    sw1.Flush();
    if (dt[playback_iterator].iden == this.event_id)
    {

        foreach (Type type in asm1.GetTypes())
        {
            if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Form)))
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.Form f = (System.Windows.Forms.Form)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                foreach (Control ctrl in f.Controls)
                {
                    if (ctrl.Handle.ToInt32() == dt[playback_iterator].hndl)
                    {
                        if (ctrl.BackColor.R == this.r_comp && ctrl.BackColor.G == this.g_comp && ctrl.BackColor.G == this.g_comp)
                        {
                            sw1.WriteLine("verification point was set and the test passed");
                            /*success ob = new success();
                            ob.Show();*/
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sw1.WriteLine("verification point test failed");
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
            sw1.Close();

            if (dt[playback_iterator].hndl == -1 && dt[playback_iterator].x == -1 && dt[playback_iterator].y == -1)
            {
                timer2.Enabled = false;
            }
            MoveMouse(dt[playback_iterator].hndl, dt[playback_iterator].x, dt[playback_iterator].y);
            if (dt[playback_iterator].click_detect.Equals("yes"))
            {
                ClickMouse(MonkeyButtons.btcLeft, dt[playback_iterator].x, dt[playback_iterator].y, 0, 0);
            }
            if (dt[playback_iterator].word != "")
            {
                ++count;
                StringBuilder wd = new StringBuilder(dt[playback_iterator].word);
                SetForegroundWindow(dt[playback_iterator].hndl);
                SendKeys.Send(dt[playback_iterator].word);
            }
            playback_iterator++;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error says just what you need to know. It is used by another process already. You might have it opened in a window of Notepad or whatever, or a different application is already using the file, just as you try to.

Comment: Don't know about that, but it seems like you're closing your File handler inside your foreach() loop, which means that on the 2nd iteration and so on, any write attempts will obviously fail.

Answer (score 0):

If this condition

```
if (dt[playback_iterator].iden == this.event_id)
```

is not true, the `StreamWriter` is not closed deterministically and next time you try to open the file you will likely get an access violation.

Use a `using` statement

```
using (StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter("E:\\testing\\check1.txt"))
{
}
```

then you can also remove the `sw1.Close()` and the writer is always closed exactly once.

Note: the error can also mean the file is used by the current process. I don't think Notepad keeps the file open, so Notepad would not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do not close the StreamWriter object, and If you are trying to append this error.. use FileStream Class for append the log every time you create inside the loop

```
string logFile = "E:\\testing\\check1.txt";
FileStream fs = new FileStream(logFile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter(fs);
sw1.Flush();
if (dt[playback_iterator].iden == this.event_id)
{

    foreach (Type type in asm1.GetTypes())
    {
        if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Form)))
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Form f = (System.Windows.Forms.Form)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            foreach (Control ctrl in f.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl.Handle.ToInt32() == dt[playback_iterator].hndl)
                {
                    if (ctrl.BackColor.R == this.r_comp && ctrl.BackColor.G == this.g_comp && ctrl.BackColor.G == this.g_comp)
                    {
                        sw1.WriteLine("verification point was set and the test passed");
                        /*success ob = new success();
                        ob.Show();*/
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sw1.WriteLine("verification point test failed");
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        if (dt[playback_iterator].hndl == -1 && dt[playback_iterator].x == -1 && dt[playback_iterator].y == -1)
        {
            timer2.Enabled = false;
        }
        MoveMouse(dt[playback_iterator].hndl, dt[playback_iterator].x, dt[playback_iterator].y);
        if (dt[playback_iterator].click_detect.Equals("yes"))
        {
            ClickMouse(MonkeyButtons.btcLeft, dt[playback_iterator].x, dt[playback_iterator].y, 0, 0);
        }
        if (dt[playback_iterator].word != "")
        {
            ++count;
            StringBuilder wd = new StringBuilder(dt[playback_iterator].word);
            SetForegroundWindow(dt[playback_iterator].hndl);
            SendKeys.Send(dt[playback_iterator].word);
        }
        playback_iterator++;

    }
}
sw1.Close();
fs.Close();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use `using` block and write to text file

```
using (StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter("E:\\testing\\check1.txt"))
{
    if (condition)
    {
        foreach (Type type in asm1.GetTypes())
        {
            if (contition)
            {
                sw1.WriteLine("verification point was set and the test passed");
            }
        }
    }
```

}